# open source flash or ajax sketchpad?

Tags: ajax, apache-flex, flash, open-source, drawing

For a non-profit (charity) site I need a simple sketchpad (drawing) component.

It should be able to:

- Let the user draw a simple black on white sketch.
- Save to server the full drawing steps.
- Save to server the final image.
- Re-play the drawing steps to future users.

http://www.sketchswap.com/ has a similar component.

Do you know where I could find an open source component to use in this project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This does not capture the drawing steps nor save the final image to a server; however, might help get you started.

*(Apologies for the horrendous sketch)*
[image: sketch]

MXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               addedToStage="addedToStageHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            //------------------------------
            //  model
            //------------------------------

            protected var lastPoint:Point;


            //------------------------------
            //  lifecycle
            //------------------------------

            protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                beginDrawing();
            }

            protected function beginDrawing():void
            {
                canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
            }

            protected function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                canvas.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

                // mark mouse down location
                lastPoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);

                // listen for movement or up/out
                canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
                canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
                canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseUpHandler);
            }

            protected function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var g:Graphics = canvas.graphics;
                g.lineStyle(1, 0x0);

                // draw line segment
                g.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
                g.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);

                // mark end of line segment
                lastPoint.x = mouseX;
                lastPoint.y = mouseY;
            }

            protected function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                canvas.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
                canvas.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
                canvas.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseUpHandler);

                beginDrawing();
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                var g:Graphics = canvas.graphics;
                g.clear();
                g.beginFill(0xff0000, 0);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                g.endFill();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="Sketchpad"
             fontSize="24"
             textAlign="center"
             paddingTop="12"
             width="100%" />

    <s:SpriteVisualElement id="canvas"
                           width="100%"
                           height="100%" />

</s:Application>
```

You could capture the steps on `mouseMoveHandler` and push them to an array.  That would capture each start and end point pair of the drawing sequence for replay.

To save to server, you could follow any number of tutorials to capture the `canvas` by creating `BitmapData` and draw `IBitmapDrawable` of the canvas to the BitmapData to save on a server.